# Why \def\xxx makes an error: "! Undefined control sequence"

Tags: tex-core, expansion, def

Why `\def\xxx{#1}` can make an error: "! Undefined control sequence" ?

It can occured because of the content of `#1` ?

An issue of expansion?

Comment: No, that won't yield an error. We'll need a full example of what you are doing.

Comment: @JosephWright  it would give `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \xxx.`.

Comment: fragile command in a moving argument

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well yes, perhaps I should have said 'the error you suggest'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\message{\def\xxx{#1}}

\bye
```

Produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \message{\def\xxx
                     {#1}}
?
```

Because in an expansion context such as `\message` or `\write` or `\edef` tokens expand but assignments do not happen.

so `\def` stays as `\def` then `\xxx` would expand, but gives the error shown as it is not defined.

As shown by the line break in the message, the `{#1}` has not yet been processed and is unrelated to the error.

Comment: Yes David. I understand totally your demonstration. So I suppose my problem is caused by an another thing. I prepare a MWE. Thanks again.