# "! Undefined control sequence." when I use "\def"

Tags: external-files, sequence, def

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{extbook}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\foo[1]{%
\def\tempfoo{#1}%
#1%
}

\newcommand\separation[1]{%
[\the\numexpr #1\relax ]%
}

\immediate\newread\myfile
\newboolean{isdisplaying}
\newcommand\displayfile[1]{
\edef\todisplay{\separation{#1} }
\edef\aftertodisplay{\separation{#1+1} }
\typeout{\todisplay}
\typeout{\aftertodisplay}
\setboolean{isdisplaying}{false}
\immediate\openin\myfile=myfile.tex
\loop\unless\ifeof\myfile
\immediate\read\myfile to\fileline
\ifthenelse{\equal{\aftertodisplay}{\fileline}}{\setboolean{isdisplaying}{false}}{}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{isdisplaying}}{\fileline}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\todisplay}{\fileline}}{\setboolean{isdisplaying}{true}}{}
\repeat
\immediate\closein\myfile

}


\begin{document}
\displayfile{2}
\end{document}
```

Here is the content of `myfile.tex`:

```
[1]
foo

[2]
\foo{bar}

[3]
baz
```

It causes this error:

```
 Undefined control sequence.
\foo #1->\def \tempfoo 
                       {#1}#1
l.39 \displayfile{2}
```

because of the `\foo` command and the `\def\tempfoo{#1}` line.

As @DavidCarliste said, it can be caused by a context of expansion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667865/237709

But I don't understand here.

**EDIT:**

SO, I suppose it is the test `\equal{\aftertodisplay}{\fileline}` that causes the error.

[*edit: that is bullshits i have written:* Maybe \equal prevent the expansion of \fileline? How can I force the expansion of \fileline in this situation?]

**EDIT (2):**
But, in my situation, the test:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\todisplay}{\protect\fileline}}
```

is always false, while it was true with:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\todisplay}{\fileline}}
```

However, in my example, `\fileline` and `\protect\fileline` have to give the same `[2]`?

In my example,  `\displayfile{2}` with `\protect\fileline` produces 0 pages...

**EDIT (3):**

a test with

```
\typeout{\fileline}
\typeout{\expandafter\protect\fileline}
```

gives an interesting output:

```
...
[2] 
[2] 
bar 
\foo{bar} 
\par 
\par
...
```

**EDIT (4):**

I just don't understand why `\protect\fileline`, which displays `[2]`, is not equal with `\todisplay`, while `\fileline`, which displays (apparently) the same `[2]`, is equal.

**EDIT (5):** (@egreg answer)
I can't explain why `\unexpanded\expandafter{\fileline}`, instead of `\protect\fileline`, works in the test `\ifthenelse`.

Comment: `\ifthenelse{\equal{\aftertodisplay}{\fileline}}`  does edef of each argument then compares with `\ifx` but the edef fails here as you can not use \foo in an edef  you need \protect\foo

Comment: You do not want to force the expansion of \fileline, you want to prevent it expanding as it contains tokens such as \foo which are not safe in an expansion context

Comment: So, yes, with ``\ifthenelse{\equal{\aftertodisplay}{\protect\fileline}`` it works. But why "edef" needs "protect", David?

Comment: Oh, ok. "Protect" prevents the expansion. That is?

Comment: well ifthenelse uses `\protected@edef` which defines `\protect` as `\noexpand\protect\noexpand`  so `\protect\foo` is  `\noexpand\protect\noexpand\foo`  which expands to  `\protect\foo`  then the edef moves on...

Comment: You are fucking amazing David!

Comment: I did write ifthenelse, you shouldn't be _so_ surprised I have an idea about what it does:-)

Comment: Oh, ok! congratulations for this great tools! but, after verification, in my situation, ``\protect\foo`` does not give the same than ``\foo`` in the test ``\ifthenelse``. I don't understand well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\ifthenelse` does full expansion, and with `\edef{\def\tempfoo{#1}}` you get almost surely an error, whether or not `\tempfoo` is defined.

You can stop full expansion by using `\protect\fileline` or

```
\unexpanded\expandafter{\fileline}
```

Remove all those `\immediate` tokens that do nothing at all.

But there are far better methods nowadays.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-data.tex}
[1]
foo

[2]
\foo{bar}

[3]
baz
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-data2.tex}
-1-
foo

-2-
\foo{bar}

-3-
baz
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% user interface

\NewDocumentCommand{\displayfile}{omm}
 {
  % #1 = separation format
  % #2 = filename
  % #3 = part to display
  \dufays_displayfile:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

%% variables

\ior_new:N \g_dufays_displayfile_ior
\str_new:N \l__dufays_displayfile_before_str
\str_new:N \l__dufays_displayfile_after_str
\bool_new:N \l__dufays_displayfile_show_bool

%% private functions and needed variants

\cs_new:Nn \__dufays_displayfile_sep:n { }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__dufays_displayfile_sep:n { e }

%% public functions

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dufays_displayfile:nnn
 {
  % if there's no optional argument, use a default separator format
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 }
   {
    \cs_set:Nn \__dufays_displayfile_sep:n { [##1] }
   }
   {
    \cs_set:Nn \__dufays_displayfile_sep:n { #1 }
   }
  \str_set:Nx \l__dufays_displayfile_before_str { \__dufays_displayfile_sep:n { #3 } ~ }
  \str_set:Nx \l__dufays_displayfile_after_str { \__dufays_displayfile_sep:e { \int_eval:n { #3+1 } } ~ }
  \ior_open:Nn \g_dufays_displayfile_ior { #2 }

  \bool_set_false:N \l__dufays_displayfile_show_bool
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_dufays_displayfile_ior
   {
    \str_if_eq:VnTF \l__dufays_displayfile_before_str { ##1 }
     {% OK, next we print
      \bool_set_true:N \l__dufays_displayfile_show_bool
     }
     {% print or set false
      \str_if_eq:VnTF \l__dufays_displayfile_after_str { ##1 }
       { \bool_set_false:N \l__dufays_displayfile_show_bool }
       { \bool_if:NT \l__dufays_displayfile_show_bool { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_dufays_displayfile_ior
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \def\tempfoo{#1}%
  #1%
}

\begin{document}

\displayfile{\jobname-data}{2}

This is \verb|\tempfoo|: \tempfoo

\displayfile[-#1-]{\jobname-data2}{3}

\end{document}
```

We can set the separator on the spots and of course input whatever file we please.

The `\ior_map_inline:Nn` function reads the file line by line. If the line equals the stated starting point, we set the `show` boolean to true. If the line equals the end point, the `show` boolean is set to false. In all other cases, the line is printed provided the boolean is true.

[image]

Comment: Your mastery of expl3 is very impressive. I have, indeed, to learn this new methods. Very impressive.

Comment: In my case, ``\unexpanded\expandafter{\fileline}`` works with the test ``ifthenelse``. I do not understand  why ``protect fileline`` does not the same, but... Thank you @egreg (and David alos of course).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what is your intend, you want to read and process only a part of the file after `[num]` label and before empty line when the `\displayfile{num}` macro is used. The `\displayfile` macro can be definded as follows:

```
\expandafter\let \expandafter\primitiveinput \csname @@input\endcsname
\def\displayfile#1{%
   \everyeof={\par}
   \long\def\scanfile ##1[#1]##2\par{##2\endinput}
   \expandafter\scanfile\primitiveinput myfile 
   \everyeof={}
}
\def\foo#1{\def\tempfoo{#1}#1}

Test:
\displayfile{1}

\displayfile{3}

\displayfile{2}
```

Note that the first line `\expandafter\let ...` followed by usage `\primitiveinput` (instead `\input`) is needed only when you are using LaTeX, because (unfortunately) LaTeX redefines `\input` primitive.

Comment: Thank you @wipet. I have to test your (I'm sure) great proposal to understand it and improve my (little) knowledge of TeX.